# How to get (in Python), part of a string in a column and transform it in a list?

Tags: python

I've just started web scraping and decided to give it a go on the classic IMDb dataset. One of my columns ('actors'), is supposed to contain the name of several actors. This is how it looks right now:

`"Director: Marc Webb | Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloë Grace Moretz"`

My goal is to exclude the Director part, and keep only the actors as a list (for some data analysis):

`["Zooey Deschanel", Joseph Gordon-Levitt", "Geoffrey Arend", "Chloe Grace Moretz"]`

What is the best way to achieve this result on ALL of my rows by using Python? Thank you!

Comment: Share the URL you are scrapping

Comment: This appears to be a straightforward string-processing task: identify the list of stars and split the list.  These steps are readily available from existing tutorials on strings.  Then you apply that to each row of your data set -- this will be included in tutorials on whatever data set package you're using.  Post your problematic code -- Stack Overflow is not a tutorial or coding resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `split()` the string:

```py
data = "Director: Marc Webb | Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloë Grace Moretz"
actors =[x.strip() for x in data.split('|')[1].split(':')[1].split(',')]
print(actors)
```

**Output:**

```
["Zooey Deschanel", "Joseph Gordon-Levitt", "Geoffrey Arend", "Chloe Grace Moretz"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "Director: Marc Webb | Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloë Grace Moretz"

#find the starting point for the part of the text which interests you.
start = string.find("Stars: ") + len("Stars: ")

#slice the string so that only the relevant part remains
string = string[start:]

#split the remaining string with a delimiter, here: ", "
output = string.split(", ")
```

As other have pointed out, of course you can do this as one line, with list comprehension:

```
output = string.rsplit(" Stars: ", 1)[-1].split(", ")
```

or

```
output = next(reversed(string.rsplit(" Stars: ", 1))).split(", ")
```

Which yields the same result but is less readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
import re

string = "Director: Marc Webb | Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloë Grace Moretz"
pattern = re.compile(r'Stars:(.+)')

stars = [star.strip() for m in pattern.findall(string) for star in m.split(",")]
```

Which yields

```
['Zooey Deschanel', 'Joseph Gordon-Levitt', 'Geoffrey Arend', 'Chloë Grace Moretz']
```

---

Or - using the `regex` module and `\G`:

```
import regex as re

string = "Director: Marc Webb | Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloë Grace Moretz"

pattern = re.compile(r'(?:\G(?!\A),\s*|Stars:\s+)\K[^,]+')

stars = pattern.findall(string)
print(stars)
```

See [**a demo for the latter on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/5rMeFw/2).

---

Or - just for the sake of academic learning - use a proper parser:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

string = "Director: Marc Webb | Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloë Grace Moretz"


class MovieVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    grammar = Grammar(r"""
        line        = director sep stars

        director    = ws? notsep colon notsep
        stars       = ws? notsep colon star+
        star        = notsep sep?

        colon       = ":"
        sep         = ~"[|,]"
        notsep      = ~"[^|,:]+"
        ws          = ~"\s+"
    """)

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_line(self, node, visited_children):
        director, _, stars = visited_children
        return {"director": director, "stars": stars}

    def visit_director(self, node, visited_children):
        *_, director = visited_children
        return director.text.strip()

    def visit_stars(self, node, visited_children):
        *_, stars = visited_children
        return stars

    def visit_star(self, node, visited_children):
        star, _ = visited_children
        return star.text.strip()


mv = MovieVisitor()
dct = mv.parse(string)
print(dct)
# {'director': 'Marc Webb', 'stars': ['Zooey Deschanel', 'Joseph Gordon-Levitt', 'Geoffrey Arend', 'Chloë Grace Moretz']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your the string is stored as `s = "Director: Marc Webb | Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloe Grace Moretz"` , then you could easily split the string as below -

### Splitting the string into actors :

1. `my_list = str.split('|')`  : This would split & convert the string into list by separating it at `|`

**Output :** `['Director: Marc Webb ', ' Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloe Grace Moretz']`

2. `my_list = my_list [1].split(':')`

**Output :** `[' Stars', ' Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloe Grace Moretz']`

3. `actors = my_list [1].split(',')`

**Output :** `[' Zooey Deschanel', ' Joseph Gordon-Levitt', ' Geoffrey Arend', ' Chloe Grace Moretz']`

---

Now you have converted your string in the desired list format. Below is the code for same -

```
s = "Director: Marc Webb | Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloe Grace Moretz"
my_list = s.split('|')   # <- this would separate director and stars

actors = my_list [1].split(':')[1].split(',') # <- this would split the elements into actors in each index


print(actors)
```

The above code would only print the actors in the list.

Comment: Never use keywords like ‘str’ in your code as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of strings containing data like you have described in your question, then you might consider doing something like the following:

```py
import pprint

imdb_actors_columns = [
        "Director: Marc Webb | Stars: Zooey Deschanel, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Geoffrey Arend, Chloë Grace Moretz",
        "Director: Alfred Hitchcock | Stars: James Stewart, Kim Novak, Barbara Bel Geddes",
        # ... etc...
]


def does_look_like_stars_col(possible_stars_column_val):
    if possible_stars_column_val:
        return possible_stars_column_val.strip().lower().startswith('stars:')
    return False


# Split apart strings into ['Director: ...', 'Stars: ...']
tokenized_columns = map(lambda s: s.split('|'), imdb_actors_columns)
# Run through generated lists of [
#   ['Director:...', 'Stars:...'], ['Director:...', 'Stars:...'],
#   ...
# ]
# And filter sublists so that we only retain the
#   [['Stars: ...'], ['Stars: ...']]
# Then use mapping to extract the first 'Stars:...' entries to top-level like:
#   ['Stars: ...', 'Stars: ...']
star_actor_columns = map(lambda a: a[0],
                         filter(bool,
                                map(lambda all_columns: list(filter(
                                    does_look_like_stars_col, all_columns)),
                                    tokenized_columns
                                    )
                                )
                         )
# Loop through all the "Stars: Name1, Name2, ..." strings, get the "Name"
#   portions, and then strip away any leading or trailing spaces so that the
#   final result is [['Name1', 'Name2', ...], ['OtherName1', 'OtherName2', ...]]
all_stars = [list(map(
    lambda s: s.strip(),
    raw_star_list.strip().replace('Stars:', '').split(',')
)) for raw_star_list in star_actor_columns]

pprint.pprint(all_stars)
```

Execution produces the following results:

```
[['Zooey Deschanel',
  'Joseph Gordon-Levitt',
  'Geoffrey Arend',
  'Chloë Grace Moretz'],
 ['James Stewart', 'Kim Novak', 'Barbara Bel Geddes']]
```

You can [check this solution out on IDEOne](https://ideone.com/Pvjm9q).